# Call to undefined method App\Notifications\NewUser::via()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I am following this tutorial

https://dev.to/povilaskorop/laravel-approve-new-registered-users-from-administrator-3nbh

I have followed every step, but when I try to register I got this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
> Call to undefined method App\Notifications\NewUser::via()

Here are my NewUser.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class NewUser extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $new_user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $new_user)
    {
        $this->new_user = $new_user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('New user has registered with email ' . $this->new_user->email)
            ->action('Approve user', route('admin.users.approve', $this->new_user->id));
    }
}
```

And My RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Notifications\NewUser;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
   
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    
        $admin = User::where('admin', 1)->first();
        if ($admin) {
            $admin->notify(new NewUser($user));
        }
    
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Any Solutions? I am using the same Laravel version as instructed (Laravel 5.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be the instructor some how misses to add the `via` method of the notification class. this method defines how a notification will be sent, like via mail or sms or slack. this method receives the notifiable class instance and handles the notification process. this returns an array of notification channels. as you are using mail (the `toMail` method) for notification, add this code block in your notification class

```
public function via ($notifiable) {
    return ['mail'];
}
```

you can read more about in laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels).